# onclick "confirm" não funciona botão cancel

Tags: php, javascript, html, front-end, back-end

Tenho um onclick confirm em meu codigo que, se ok, ele envia uma variavel para uma pagina em especifico. Se cancel... ele deveria cancelar a operação.

Porém mesmo se clicar em cancel, ele está enviando a variavel para a página.

Segue o código:

```
   <a onclick="confirm('mensagem de confirmação')" href= "close.php?id_os=<?php echo $temp['id']?>";>
        <div style="width:5%; height:100%">enviar
        </div>
    </a>
```

**Obs:** o PHP inserido está ok. Na verdade, como dito anteriormente, em qualquer botão que eu clique (ok ou cancel), ele envia a variavel para a página em questão.

Comment: Coloca um return antes do confirm: return confirm('mensagem de confirmação')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisa cancelar o evento do click, com um `return false` por exemplo.
Como o `confirm` já retorna `true` ou `false` basta usar `return confirm` assim no seu exemplo:

```
 <a onclick="return confirm('mensagem de confirmação')">
```

Assim, se confirmar será direciona (`true`), se cancelar não será acionado o link (`false`)